# Error while creating site definition in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, site-definition

I written a program to create site definition in visual studio. I am running below  stsadm commandlines in post deployment process. I added below code in the **"Post-Deployment command line"** window.

```
stsadm.exe -o deletesite -url http://sp2010
stsadm.exe -o createsite -owneremail admin@contoso.com  -url http://sp2010 -sitetemplate "STS#0" -title "My Site"
```

These lines are not executing. It is giving error with code **4294967294**
But if i run these lines in command prompt these are executing successfully. What mistake I done here.

Comment: welcome in the sharepoint world. To diagnose such unobvious issue, split your project into multiple features, that you debug one by one. Only after that, reference the features in your onet.xml. Try to avoid putting things in this files in general, and prefer using feature. Also, you should check in the ULS logs if the exact source of the error is shown

Comment: ... Wild guess... Are you running Visual Studio with Run As Admin, right?

Comment: Yes I am running as administraotr.